# style.marginTop con el valor de una variable angular

Tags: angular, angular5

Estoy tratando de dar la propiedad style.marginTop.px a mi html cargando el valor de una variable angular. Algo así:

Template:

```
 <div class="map-container">
  <div class="map">
  <div class="marcador" [style.marginTop.px]="top" [style.marginLeft.px]="left"><b>X</b></div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
private moveTheMark(place: any): void {
    switch(place) {
      case '0':
        this.top = '163px';
        this.left = '420px';
        break;
      case '1':
        this.top = '165px';
        this.left = '467px';
        break;

    }
  }
```

A la función moveTheMark se le llama en el ngOnChanges y modifica el valor de top y left en función del parametro place. Sin embargo no consigo hacerlo funcionar. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿que versión de angular estas usando?

Comment: Actualmente uso la versión 5 de angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando mal la directiva de style intenta quitando el px algo asi

```
    <div class="map-container">
        <div class="map">
            <div class="marcador" [style.marginTop]="top" [style.marginLeft]="left">
             <b>X</b>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Estas agregando de mas el valor px a la directiva

Comment: Tal cual. Yo creo que de tanto buscar he acabado mezclando conceptos. Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!.